# Oven Hood Light Fixture Borked - Help Please

Tags: electrical, repair, light-fixture

Country: Canada

I was replacing my oven hood light fixtures with LED bulbs. One of the LED bulbs swapped in no problem. The other LED bulb was having trouble getting contact and subsequently a current. So I brute forced it a bit and out came the bulb with the thread assembly as well.

Here are some pictures: https://i.stack.imgur.com/iqntW.jpg

As you can see the thread portion (gold) was attached to the socket with two (rivet like) structures. These two structures snapped off and brought the whole thread assembly out of the hood fixture.

I tried putting a couple of different light bulbs into the bare socket to see if the light would work by touching the contact but the bulbs would not work.
Have I totally borked the socket? Is there any way for me to fix it? Is there any way for an electrician to fix this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The socket itself is probably shot, but you should be able to fix the range hood by replacing the socket.  It looks to be held into the chassis by a couple of retaining clips and should come out pretty easily from the back, although you'll probably have to remove the cover to take it out properly.  It looks like [this part](http://www.centralvacuumstores.com//broan-r111630-light-socket-assembly) is what you would need to fix it (but don't take my word for it -- make sure to do your own research and verify that the replacement part looks the same as the original).  I found this by Googling for "Nutone Allure range hood replacement parts".  If it is indeed the correct part, then it should just plug right in.